# Building CTE containing two joins from different tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, common-table-expression

I'm trying to build a CTE for displaying parent-child relationship in tandem with table names and descriptions (as illustrated below). I have a query for selecting fact tables and one that selects all tables dimension and fact tables alike as well as related columns etc seperately but I can't seem to make them into one when building a CTE no matter which guide I follow. Any ideas on how this can be done? I want it to look like below and I'm using the AdventureWorksDw2012.

```
   Parent |  Table name | Column name | Description
|___________________________________________________
|FactTbl1 |  DimResel  |   Phone     |  Phone nr to empl
|            DimProd   |   ListPrice |  Rec. price to cust.
|FactTbl2 |  DimCurr   |   CurrencyN.|  Name of currency
|
```

EDIT: Added queries as requested by @Tyron78

These are the two queries I'm trying to combine:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT tbl.name
    FROM sys.tables AS tbl
    LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkey
    ON tbl.object_id = fKey.parent_object_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS rKey 
    ON tbl.object_id = rKey.referenced_object_id
    WHERE rKey.referenced_object_id IS NULL


    SELECT DISTINCT
    t.TABLE_SCHEMA AS [Parent], 
    t.TABLE_NAME AS [Object],
    t.COLUMN_NAME AS [Type], 
    cd.value AS [Description]
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS t
    INNER JOIN syscolumns c
    ON c.name = t.COLUMN_NAME
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties cd
    ON cd.major_id = c.id
    AND cd.minor_id = c.colid
    AND cd.name = 'MS_Description'
    WHERE t.TABLE_NAME in ('MyTables')
```

This is the CTE-Query I tried but didn't work

```
WITH Parents
AS ( SELECT DISTINCT tbl.name
FROM sys.tables AS tbl
LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkey
    ON tbl.object_id = fKey.parent_object_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS rKey 
    ON tbl.object_id = rKey.referenced_object_id
    WHERE rKey.referenced_object_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT
    t.TABLE_SCHEMA AS [Parent], 
    t.TABLE_NAME AS [Object],
    t.COLUMN_NAME AS [Type], 
    cd.value AS [Description]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS t
INNER JOIN syscolumns c
    ON c.name = t.COLUMN_NAME
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties cd
    ON cd.major_id = c.id
    AND cd.minor_id = c.colid
    AND cd.name = 'MS_Description'
    WHERE t.TABLE_NAME in ('MyTables'))
SELECT *
FROM Parents
```

Comment: please look here to improve question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Please provide us with the two table structures and the query you already tried.